# Expected Number of Points in Two-Player Dice Game

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-probability

I came across this problem online and it has been in the back of my mind ever since. I'm currently taking a probability course so please forgive my limited knowledge if I'm missing a key concept.

**Problem.** Let's play a dice game with two players. Both players roll a fair dice. The winner gains a number of points equal to the difference of the two dice (if same number are rolled, the round is tied and no points are won/lost). E.g. player 1 rolls a $5$, player 2 rolls a $3$, player 1 wins, and gains $(5-3=2)$ points.

The game ends if a player reaches 20 points or more. If after 10 rounds and no one has 20 points, no one wins.

**Question.** What is the expected number of points gained in each round by the winning player?

**My Work So Far.** Intuitively, I wanted to take the conditional probability of gaining $1-5$ points and multiply those probabilities with their associated points and add these products which should give me the expected number of points gained in each round.

Let event $A_i$ be the event that the *winning* player gains $i$ points. The chance of winning a round is $\frac{15}{36}$, so:

$A_i=P(\text{gaining i points}|\text{winning})$

So my answer is:

$\sum_{i=1}^{5}i\times A_i=\sum_{i=1}^{5}i\times\frac{(6-i)/36}{15/36}=\frac{7}{3}$

This is sadly not the answer, I feel like I'm missing a key insight or I'm tackling this problem with the wrong concepts.

**Clarification** It seems like my work was to just calculate a single round. I feel very lost in an analytical solution for an entire game. By "winner" I meant the winner of the entire game. The winner is determined if they ever reach 20 points *or more.*

Comment: Can you clarify how you calculate expected value?

Comment: Are you sure the question is the points gained by the player who wins one round, not points gained by the player who wins the whole game?

Comment: Your computation just concerns a single round, not the whole game, but I don't understand it even for a single round.  It's easy to do the computation directly (just averaging over all $36$ outcomes), and the answer is $\frac {35}{18}$, again just for a single round (with no condition).

Comment: In your "Question", does "winning player" refer to the winning player of the current round only, or to the overall winner of the game who scores a total of 20?

Comment: This could be approached via backwards induction, starting with a list of all the possible winning states, but I expect just simulating it is better.  At a minimum, simulation will tell you the answer, which you can then compare against anything you get analytically.

Comment: Does a player win if he reaches more than 20 points after the last round?

Comment: Oh, I think that's what I was missing, I was only considering a single round and not the whole game. I'm able to simulate this in Python but is there an analytical solution?

Comment: Yes, a player wins more than 20 points after the last round.

Comment: I meant "winning player" as in the overall winner of the game.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this problem has a nice solution since it was placed online but I did not find it. Therefore I will give here the brute force solution.

Let
$$
p_k(n_1,n_2)
$$
be the probability, that after $k$ rounds the players have $n_1$ and $n_2$ points, respectively, where we assume a non-stop game.

Then we have:
$$
p_k(n_1,n_2)=\frac16p_{k-1}(n_1,n_2)+\sum_{i=1}^5\big[p_{k-1}(n_1-i,n_2)+p_{k-1}(n_1,n_2-i)\big]\frac{6-i}{36}.
$$
This recurrence together with the condition:
$$
p_0(n_1,n_2)=\begin{cases}
1,&n_1=n_2=0\\
0,&\text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
allows us to calculate the probability for any $k,n_1,n_2$.

Due to symmetry, the probability that a player will as first surpass in the $k$-th round a total of $t$ points and, in doing so, accumulate $n$ points, can be expressed as follows:
$$
P_k(n,t)=\sum_{i=n-t}^{5}\frac{6-i}{36}\sum_{n'=0}^{t} p_{k-1}(n-i,n').
$$
Now we are ready to compute the expected number of points gained in each round by the winning player:
$$
\left[\frac nk\right]=\frac{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{10}\sum_{n=20}^{24}
P_k(n,19)\frac{n}k}{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^{10}\sum_{n=20}^{24}
P_k(n,19)}.
$$

My calculation gives the result:
$$
\left[\frac nk\right]=\frac{6480877805871607}{2825235479368820} 
\approx2.29392. 
$$

The probability that the game will be finished in 10 rounds is only about $4.4\%$.